# Modding Android Apps

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I Was Modding A Game Earlier Which Used C# Dlls But Now With Updated Unity Engine They Have LibIL2CPP
So I Converted libil2cpp To Normal C# Dll's Which Had Offsets For libil2cpp.so

I Modded The Game I Could Not Find Some Function Such As Keys Function.
So I Tried To COmpare A Pre-modded Game APk's Libil2cpp With Original Game.
The Hex Editor Told Me That They Both Are Identical .
So I Got To Conclusion That They Were Not Editing The Original LIB.
But The Modded App Had A Extra Lib Called libnotlib.so

Can Someone Tell How They Created This Lib I Have No Idea About What It Is .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to decompile the wrong file. `libIL2CPP` is the layer that allows Unity code to execute on other devices. All game code is typically stored in `Assembly-CSharp`.

It would make sense that an original and modded game's `libIL2CPP` be identical as it is a required dependency for the Unity app to run in the first place. In fact, it should be identical between games built with the same version and for the same platform [(assuming their scripting backend is IL2CPP and not Mono/.NET)](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/windowsstore-scriptingbackends.html).